# Why does this code print nothing?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm just starting to learn python3 and I do not understand why the code does not work.

I wrote a function and three tests for it. Here's what the function should do :

- Performs a search for a number x in array A from 0 to N-1 index 
  inclusive.
- Returns the index of the element x in the array A.
  Or -1, if there is none.
- If there are several identical elements in the array, equal to x,
  then return the index of the first account.

```
def array_search(A:list, N:int, x:int):
    for k in range(N):
        if A[k] == x:
            return k
    return -1

def test_array_search():
    A1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    m = array_search(A1, 5, 8)
    if m  == -1:
        print("#test1 - ok")
    else:
        print("#test1 - fail")

    A2 = [-1, -2, -3, -4, -5]
    m = array_search(A2, 5, -3)
    if m  == 2:
        print("#test1 - ok")
    else:
        print("#test1 - fail")

    A3 = [10, 20, 30, 10, 10]
    m = array_search(A3, 5, 10)
    if m  == 0:
        print("#test1 - ok")
    else:
        print("#test1 - fail")    


    test_array_search()
```

Comment: Unindent `test_array_search()` at the bottom.

Comment: the function call is inside the function, remove the indentation at the bottom

Comment: @roganjosh thanks, write as an answer and I'll take it =)

Answer (score 0):

You have not actually called test_array_search function outside. So, just write the test_array_search function outside